# Как получить данные из массива в другой функции, которые пришли из сервера

Tags: javascript, fetch

Я получил данные из сервера, у меня есть кнопка, по которой я буду выводить некие данные из массива, повесил событие на кнопку и вывожу функцию. Как мне в этой функции получить данные из массива, которые пришли мне из сервера. Спасибо

```
// Selectors
const search = document.querySelector('#search');
const checkBox = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
const lineLength = document.querySelector('#line_length');
const subString = document.querySelector('#substring');


// Event
lineLength.addEventListener('click', one);


// Functions
function one() {
  // тут я вывожу некие данные из масcива, но я не пойму, как их тут получить
}


// Request
async function getResponse() {
  let response = await fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json');
  let result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: что мешает сразу респонс затолкать, вместо отдельной функции на клик ?

Comment: У меня будет две функции как минимум, поэтому приходится вот так...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const lineLength = document.querySelector('#line_length');
const subString = document.querySelector('#substring');

lineLength.addEventListener('click', one);

// Request
 async function getResponse() {
  try{
  let response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  let result = await response.json();
  return result
  } catch(err) {
   console.log(err.message)
  }
}

// Functions
async function one() {
const res = await getResponse()
console.log(res)
  // тут я вывожу некие данные из масcива, но я не пойму, как их тут получить
}
```

```html
<button id="line_length">
click
</button>
```